# Mailgun emails work on local but not server

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2, mailgun

I am using the same setup as on the server. I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu, then I am using Docker to host an Ubuntu image with runs my Laravel project on nginx and php7. My local is setup up the exact same, I use the same Docker image and everything.

When I test my emails on my local they work seamlessly, no errors or problems but as soon as I test it on my EC2 I get the following error in Laravel:

> Swift_TransportException: Connection to tcp://smtp.mailgun.org:587 Timed Out in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:404

I have tried using ports 25, 2525 and 465 butt he exact same result. Here are my env variables:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@placeholder.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=5uup3rL0nGPa55w0RdY0uPr0bablykn0
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@placeholder.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="placeholder Team"

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=placeholder.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-MyK3y1s0ac001y0uw15hy0uhadi7h3h3
```

*The secret and password is fake data*

On Mailgun's dashboard I have verified my domain (locally I use `localhost.MYDOMAIN.com` pointing to `127.0.0.1`) and all checks are green except for `mxa.mailgun.org` and `mxb.mailgun.org` because we are using gmail for our emails. Not sure if this is the source but I cannot risk disabling the emails just for a test.

If I telnet to Mailgun using `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 25` (*or any other port*) I get a connection, so I do get access.

I also applied to relieve the email sending throttling on my server that Amazon puts onto EC2 servers. Not sure when this will actually be in effect so not sure if it will help or not (It might)

I am not sure why I only get a timeout on my server and it works on my local but any advice would be appreciated!

I did try searching around for answers but did not succeed.

**WORKAROUND** If anyone is struggling with this same issue, it is not worth the effort, rather just implement the Mailgun API, this way you do not have to put up with these issues, it is what I have now done which, had I known about the issues I would have faced, would have done from the start. *So still no solution from my side, just avoided it* and also why I am not updating with an answer and instead just updating with an edit. Not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Please do not provide your secret key and password all over the world...

Comment: I faked those so no worries.

Comment: I tried updating my Security Groups on AWS so that it accepts all traffic incoming for ports 25 and 465 but still got this error: 

Swift_TransportException: Connection to tcp://smtp.mailgun.org:465 Timed Out in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:404

Comment: Also, I used port 465 for my new tests in case someone mentions the different ports, AWS just did not allow me to set port 587 for SMPTS on the Security Groups

Comment: Incoming security group rules are not relevant.  Don't change MX.  Verify that you actually have Internet access from this container.  `ping 8.8.8.8` or `curl icanhazip.com`... basic troubleshooting before complex troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is internet access `ping 8.8.8.8` does work and I also connect to a few APIs so Internet is not a problem and outbound TCP is working, just not sure why I get the timeout.

Comment: Add you have  domain then register domain with mailgun
And if you only have server IP then add that ip to mailgun
Login to mailgun -> Sending -> IPs -> Manage IP and then add your ip.